# Multiply two matrices column-wise to obtain vector

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, vectorization, matrix-multiplication

I have two equally-sized matrices `A` and `B`, which are actually a collection of independent column vectors. I need to perform a "matrix-multiplication" (`*` or `mtimes`) for every column in `A` with the corresponding column in `B`. As a result I get a vector whose number of elements equals the number of columns. The easy way is a loop, but I need to this thousands of times and my matrices are at least of size `>2000x16...200` - so vectorization would help.

Additionally, there is also a weighting matrix involved.

Consider the following example:

```
nDof  = 250;    % number of rows
nCols = 16;     % number of columns

% Example complex matrices 
A = rand(nDof,nCols) + 1j*rand(nDof,nCols); 
B = rand(nDof,nCols) + 1j*rand(nDof,nCols); 
% Weighting Matrix
W = rand(nDof,nDof)  + 1j*rand(nDof,nDof); 

% Option 1: Loop - multpliy matrices column by column with/without wighting
X1 = zeros(nCols,1);  Y1 = zeros(nCols,1);
for ii = 1:nCols
    X1(ii) = A(:,ii)'     * B(:,ii);
    Y1(ii) = A(:,ii)' * W * B(:,ii);
end

% Option 2: avoid loop
X2temp = A'     * B;
Y2temp = A' * W * B;
% => seemingly diagonal elements are what I need
X2 = diag(X2temp);
Y2 = diag(Y2temp);
    
% Test
disp(X2-X1)
disp(Y2-Y1)
```

As you can see, in Option 2, I tried to avoid the loop by just multiplying the matrices directly. The diagonal elements of the resulting matrix are very close to the result of the loop. But only close and not equal. Although the error is probably significantly small for my case, it appears to be too large to be caused only by floating-point inaccuracies.

Test results:

```
X2-X1  =  1.0e-13 *

  0.426325641456060 + 0.355271367880050i
  0.284217094304040 + 0.852651282912120i
 -0.284217094304040 - 0.426325641456060i
  0.000000000000000 + 0.142108547152020i
 -0.284217094304040 - 0.213162820728030i
  0.284217094304040 - 0.923705556488130i
  0.568434188608080 + 0.355271367880050i
  0.000000000000000 + 0.142108547152020i
  0.000000000000000 + 0.071054273576010i
 -0.284217094304040 + 0.497379915032070i
  0.284217094304040 - 0.426325641456060i
 -0.284217094304040 + 0.142108547152020i
  0.000000000000000 + 0.000000000000000i
 -0.284217094304040 + 0.142108547152020i
 -0.284217094304040 - 0.213162820728030i
  0.284217094304040 - 0.284217094304040i

Y2-Y1 = 1.0e-10 *

  0.000000000000000 + 0.036379788070917i
 -0.018189894035459 + 0.072759576141834i
 -0.072759576141834 - 0.072759576141834i
  0.036379788070917 - 0.109139364212751i
  0.090949470177293 + 0.054569682106376i
 -0.109139364212751 + 0.054569682106376i
  0.109139364212751 - 0.163709046319127i
  0.018189894035459 - 0.127329258248210i
  0.072759576141834 - 0.018189894035459i
  0.036379788070917 - 0.036379788070917i
  0.018189894035459 + 0.000000000000000i
  0.109139364212751 - 0.072759576141834i
 -0.018189894035459 - 0.018189894035459i
  0.000000000000000 - 0.054569682106376i
 -0.018189894035459 + 0.036379788070917i
  0.036379788070917 - 0.036379788070917i
```

So. **What is the correct way to do this? What is the fastest way to do this?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do element-wise products and then do a `sum` along the first axis:

```
X = sum(conj(A) .* B, 1);
Y = sum(conj(A) .* (W*B), 1);
```

Edit: Actually, there is a built-in function doing exactly that called [`dot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dot.html)
:

```
X = dot(A, B);
Y = dot(A, W*B);
```

Transpose (`.'`) or adjoint (`'`) the results, if you want to have them as column vectors.

I'm guessing that `dot` will tend to be more accurate that the `sum( .* )` variant, mostly because it can better use FMA operations. If you want to check the accuracy, I suggest to generate random single precision data, then compute the dot-products with either approach in single precision and compare it to what you get if you convert it to double precision first.

Comment: Is it really what he wants to do though?

Comment: @BillBokeey that's at least what `X1(ii) = A(:,ii)' * B(:,ii);  Y1(ii) = A(:,ii)' * W * B(:,ii);` computes (ignoring numerical noise).

Comment: @chtz The result is literally the same like in my approach. Same errors, even same calculation time. But an error compared to the loop of magnitude 1.0e-10 is quite large to be called numerical noise, don't you agree? I am still not entirely convinced.

Comment: I found that there is also a `dot` function and I added a paragraph how you could check which approach is (in general) more accurate.

Comment: For a difference in computation time (especially compared to your option 2) you probably need to increase `nCols` significantly. And generally, loops are not slow in Matlab, except in very old versions, or, e.g., if you incrementally grow matrices inside the loop.

Comment: @RobertSeifert “error compared to the loop”. It is likely that `sum` is more precise than the addition in your loop: https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2021/09/07/a-faster-and-more-accurate-sum/

Comment: As a point of reference, I did a study of dot( ) vs mtimes( ) for this very calculation several years ago and found that dot( ) was slower and less accurate than mtimes( ) or sum( ) when comparing to extended precision calculations using the Symbolic Toolbox.  I don't know if that comparison still holds true today. Another advantage of mtimes( ) is that it doesn't physically form the conjugate to do the operation, whereas calling conj( ) explicitly of course does. So if you can somehow formulate things with mtimes( ) or pagemtimes( ) I would explore that route.

Comment: @JamesTursa My own variant and both variants of @chtz seem to be equivalent in R2017b in terms of accuaracy and speed. What I do not like about `diag( "mtimes" )` approach, is that a lot of matrix elements are calculated, which are then omitted by `diag`. Of course, if speed-wise that is not an issue, than why not.